# Rep changes not shown on profile view

Tags: discussion

Perhaps this is by design, but I notice that rep changes caused by my own actions are not always listed in the detailed view of rep events.  Now, of course I know when I do a down-vote or something, but a consequence is that if one were to go through and add up all the events displayed, the total would not match what SE says is the total.  Now, I would never do that, but I notice that a lot of people consider reputation as a serious personal matter and get quite vocal if they think they have been "cheated" in some way.

But what's my question?  Simply whether this is a bug or an intentional design choice.

Comment: Which view are you talking about? The one in the top bar which shows if you gain and sometimes if you lose rep? Your profile’s [*summary*](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau?tab=topactivity) tab? Your profile’s [*reputation*](http://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau?tab=reputation) tab?

Comment: For example, I down voted something, which of course costs me one point.  That was shown on the drop down, but not in the detailed list that appears when I click on the word "reputation" in my profile.  That list apparently only shows changes triggered by other people.  No big deal, just curious.

Comment: It’s there for me … (I had to go back in time to find a post I actually downvoted, but it’s there all right) Not sure where the problem is?

Comment: Hmm.  If it's inconsistent, that's even odder.

Comment: Are you sure that the downvoted post did not get removed? If so, the entire thing just silently disappears …

Comment: Well, actually, I downvoted two "answers" that weren't, and then looked at the profile and it had no negatives (except months earlier).  But today, one of the does show up, and the other non-answer has been deleted.  So, it's just weird.  Delayed entry into the list, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I already said that I can see them on my profile, but here it is again, backed with screenshots. Taken from my profile pages on [Anime](https://anime.stackexchange.com/users/13532/jan?tab=reputation), [Chemistry](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/7475/jan?tab=reputation) and [Travel](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/43483/jan?tab=reputation).

[image: Anime] [image: Chemistry] [image: Travel]

Except for downvotes (which I can find on [your user profile’s reputation tab](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/12555/wgroleau?tab=reputation)), just about every single reputation-negative activity except for *unaccept, unaccepted* and *user was removed* can be seen there. Flagging your post for [status-norepro](/questions/tagged/status-norepro).

Comment: I had no reason to doubt your word, so "evidence" wasn't necessary.  On the other hand, from the images, I can't tell whether "-1 downvoted" means someone voted against you or you voted against someone else.  I was asking about the fact that when I gave up a point in order to vote against an "answer" that told me to fix a Mac problem by putting something on the C: drive :-_) that minus did not appear in my list.  But, interestingly, it is on the list now.  So, just one of those things.  Not a refresh issue, because I opened the list after doing the downvote.

Comment: @WGroleau *downvoted* means that you hit the negative button on someone else’ post. *Downvote*, analogous to *upvote* means that you were on the receiving end. Therefore, *downvoted* is valued -1 while *downvote* is valued -2 ;)